# Trying to show certain "storyline" in HTML div tab when JS Variable is equiv to x

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello folks and thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

I've asked a couple of questions recently as I am trying to make a HTML5/CSS/JavaScript based incremental game and I've run into a snag and wondering if someone could provide some help if possible.

The main game display will be a series of tab's along the top of the screen and when each tab is clicked different information will be displayed on screen relevant to each seperate section of the game's content:

i.e Tab 1 | Home // Tab 2 | Village // Tab 3 | Research etc.

Now when each of these tab's is clicked below them will be the title of the tab in a "h3" tag and then below that "h3" tab title "h3" I want to display different story content depending on the variable number located in the javascript file only problem is I'm not sure how to make the html file check the javascript file for a certain variable in order to tell the html file which part of the storyline to display when that tab is clicked.

So in summary I'm looking to find a way to display story content in each "html tab" when a javasctipt variable is equivalent to X

I think... Unless there is a simpler way to do this (The answer is probably really simple as well and it's just not clicking in my brain what I need to do...)

current code sample below:

```
<div id="clearing" class="tabcontent">
                    <h3>The Clearing</h3>
                    {if JS Variable === 1
                        <p>You wake up to find yourself in a strange clearing unaware of what has happened to you.
                        You scramble around with blurred vision feeling a crunch under your bare feet as you stumble around...
                        "Ugh... Where am I..., What on earth happened to me?"</p>

                        <p>You continue scrambling around and you hear faint noises in the distance...</p>
                    }

                    {if JS Variable === 2
                        <p>You make it back to the clearing after being greeted by the local population and you try 
                           to work out what your next step will be, For now though you going to need some shelter 
                           because it look's like it's going to rain quite heavily and you don't want to be caught 
                           outside in that.</p>
                    }
                </div>
```

Many thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend splitting up JavaScript and HTML from another. Otherwise you'll end up in a mess.

What you're basically looking for is something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="home">Home</div>
<div id="village">Village</div>
<div id="research">Research</div>

<div id="clearing" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>The Clearing</h3>
  <p id="text"</p>
</div>
```

javascript file:

```
document.getElementById("home").onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "your home text";
}

document.getElementById("village").onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "your village text";
}


document.getElementById("research").onclick = function () {
  if(variable === 3) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "your research text";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "other research text";
  }
}
```

so when you click on home, village or research the text inside the clearing div should change.

Comment: Thank you David, I will try this out now and see what happen's :)

EDIT: Would I also be able to add an IF statement to this function to display different text when the variable is a certain number?

Comment: From where do you get the variable? And how is it changed?
Check out the changes i made to the research function.

Comment: the variable will be stored in the file js/game.js and I am wanting to increase the variable by 1 (to change the story content that is visiable in that tab at any given time) when the player has achieved a "certain goal" i.e earned 500 money or generated 1000 power or researched X research.

I haven't had chance to check your edit yet I will do so shortly as I am about to post another question for something different (same project different problem).

Comment: you could just move my code into your game.js file and then depending on your variable state change the text (like shown in my example code)

Comment: Thank you David, I have done this now and I am currently trying to figure out how to change the variable to match the condition I will mark your answer as correct in the meantime, Thank you for your help :)